# Is $TS^2\setminus Z$ a $S^2$- fibre bundle on the puntured plane?(Swapping the role of fibre points and base space)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fibre-bundles

Let $X=TS^2\setminus Z$ where $Z$ is the zero section of the tangent bundle of $S^2$.

Is there a $S^2$- fiber bundle structure on $(X,\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\},q)$ for some continuous fibre map $q$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your question means: Is $X$ a fiber bundle over $\mathbb{R}^2 -0$, the answer is no. $X$ is homotopy equivalent to the unit tangent bundle of $S^2$, which is in turn homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^3$. Also, $R^2 -0 \simeq S^1$. Now look at the exact sequence of the fibration; you'd conclude $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^3) = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You mean $\pi_1$, right?

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler It implies this of both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$.

Comment: I actually meant $\pi_2$ but $\pi_1$ would also work.

Comment: Thank you very much  for  your interesting  answer  and your  attention.